# what is the `A-` binding?

Tags: key-bindings

On Emacs, if I type `C-h, b` a list of keybinds come up, including:

[image]

what is `A-` and how do I access it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`A-` is the Alt modifier.  Which, for clarity, is almost definitely *not* the key labelled 'Alt' on your keyboard -- that's recognised as the Meta modifier.

Most people simply don't have this modifier key.  It's relatively common for people to configure Super and Hyper modifiers on modern keyboards but, probably on account of the potential for confusion, one doesn't tend to hear about people using the Alt modifier in Emacs these days.  (It was useful on keyboards which had an 'Alt' key and a 'Meta' key, though.)

If you have a need, you can invoke the Alt modifier like so:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Followed by whichever key you wish to be modified.  In your examples: <kbd>*</kbd>

```
Function key map translations Starting With C-x @:
key             binding
---             -------

C-x @ S         event-apply-shift-modifier
C-x @ a         event-apply-alt-modifier
C-x @ c         event-apply-control-modifier
C-x @ h         event-apply-hyper-modifier
C-x @ m         event-apply-meta-modifier
C-x @ s         event-apply-super-modifier
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27419718/324105 might also be useful reading regarding the `event-apply-*-modifier` functions.

Comment: +1 for your answer. I would have never found this answer given a million guesses. In my kbd, I have the keys labelled `Alt`, `Cntl`, `Win_key`, `Shift` and `Caps_lock`. My `Alt` key behaves as the emacs's `Meta` key. Are there specific keyboards which have an additional `Alt` key?

Comment: @Prasanna Plenty of keyboards have two keys labelled "Alt" (one either side of the space bar, typically), but I think it unlikely that you'd find a keyboard with both a "Meta" key and an "Alt" key.  Some old keyboard certainly had both, though.  https://www.quora.com/How-did-Alt-and-Ctrl-become-standard-modifier-keys-on-computer-keyboards shows some examples.  The 'space cadet' keyboard not only has an "Alt mode" key, but it even has "Alt lock".

Comment: See also the top four entries of http://xahlee.info/kbd/lisp_keyboards.html