# Capital A Meaning in Emacs Syntax?

Tags: keyboard-layout, modifier-key

I'm familiar with `M` being the modifier key in Emacs syntax but I'm reading the instructions for a package and it is telling me to prepend the modifier with `A`.

```
A-M-n
```

I've tried a few different things but I can't see to find what `A` is refering to here?

Comment: See the Emacs manual, node [User Input](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/User-Input.html). See also node [Windows Keyboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Keyboard.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the \`A-\` binding?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44889/what-is-the-a-binding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs recognizes 5 modifier keys (arguably 6 depending on how you feel about `Shift`):

`<Control>` (`C-`), `<Meta>` (`M-`), `<Super>` (`s-`), `<Hyper>` (`H-`), and `<Alt>` (`A-`).

This capital A means that this key-sequence uses the uncommon `<Alt>` modifier. Since your `Alt` key, if you even have one, is most likely used for the `<Meta>` modifier, you probably do not have a key currently mapped to work as this modifier. However, you can simulate its use with the key sequence `C-x @ a`. In this case, `C-x @ a M-n` is equivalent to `A-M-n`. (The similar key sequences `C-x @ h` and `C-x @ s` are equivalent to using the `<Hyper>` and `<Super>` modifiers, respectively.)

It's worth noting that it is possible to rebind modifier keys to work as different modifiers. For example, on Windows, the `Alt` key can be rebound to work as the `<Alt>` modifier by setting the variable `w32-alt-is-meta` to a `nil` value.